# Using enzyme, How to find a child component in a component react if they are result of function return

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm using jest/enzyme and want to check existence child elements of React component
if i have function as component child

```
const children = () => (
    <>
      <div>...</div>
      <div>...</div>
    </>
) 
return <Component>{children}</Component>;
```

why i can't do like this

```
  test('Should render div', () => {
    wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
    const component = wrapper.find(Component);
    expect(component.exists()).toBe(true);  //return true
    const children = wrapper.find('div')
    expect(children.exists()).toBe(false);  //return false
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your children function is basically a render prop and shallow doesn't render it. You can however trigger the rendering by calling it as a function like

```
shallow(
  shallow(<MyComponent />)
    .find(Component)
    .prop('children')()
)
```

So your test will look like

```
test('Should render div', () => {
    wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
    const component = wrapper.find(Component);
    expect(component.exists()).toBe(true);  //return true
    const renderProp = shallow(component.prop('children')());
    const children = renderProp.find('div');
    expect(children.exists()).toBe(true); 
  });
```